# Not getting email when user clicks the submit button

Tags: php

I have added a form (Career details like Name,Resume upload etc)on my website , I want this functionality: 
Whenever user clicks on the submit button his details an email will be sent to the admin containing all the details of user.

Now everything is working but I am not getting any kind of email.Following is the code:

```
$formproc->AddRecipient('***@gmail.com');
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: I am using this :
http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/contact-form-attachment.html

Comment: if youre not getting any email then everything is not working? do you get any errors? is mail setup properly in php?

Comment: No i am not getting any error . yes i have entered the correct mail.

Comment: no, is php::mail() [configured](http://www.quackit.com/php/tutorial/php_mail_configuration.cfm) properly?

Comment: @DevDonkey how to do that?